# Work-Energy Theorem Problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

I found my problem on Yahoo Answers: 
[here](http://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20141105221955AApzsqF).

I do not understand where $$-\Delta U =\Delta K $$ comes from. In class, we learned that 
$$W_\textrm{net}=\Delta(K)$$

But we didn't see any of what the guy uses in his answer. Could someone provide an answer using the work-energy theorem, please ?

Comment: Please make your question self-contained. Without the link to Yahoo Answers, it is completely unclear what this question might be asking.

Answer (score 1):

Work done $w$ is given (in one-dimension) by

$$w = \int_{\mathbf x_1}^{\mathbf x_2} ~\mathbf F\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf x\tag I$$

When the force is conservative, it can be expressed by scalar potential energy function $U(\mathbf x)$ viz.

$$ \begin{align}F &= - \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}~U\\ \implies U(\mathbf x) &= -\int_{\mathbf x_0}^{\mathbf x} \mathbf F\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf x + U(\mathbf x_0) \,, \tag{II}\end{align}$$ where $U(\mathbf x_0)$ is an arbitrary constant.

Now, as OP said

$$\Delta ~\textrm{KE} = K_2 - K_1 =\int_{\mathbf x_1}^{\mathbf x_2} ~\mathbf F\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf x $$

This can be re-written as

$$\begin{align}K_2 + \left[-\int_{\mathbf x_0}^{\mathbf x_2} ~\mathbf F\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf x\right] & = K_1 +\left[-\int_{\mathbf x_0}^{\mathbf x_1} ~\mathbf F\cdot \mathrm d\mathbf x\right]\\\implies~~
K_2 + \left[U(\mathbf x_2)-U(\mathbf x_0)\right] & = K_1 +\left[U(\mathbf x_1)-U(\mathbf x_0)\right]\\
\implies~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  K_2 - K_1 & = -~U(\mathbf x_2) + U(\mathbf x_1)\\ \implies~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \Delta ~\textrm{KE} &  =-~\Delta ~U\,.\tag{III} \end{align} $$

Comment: I think you are missing a minus sign: Delta KE = - Delta U... Conservation of energy. Assuming Delta U = U_f - U_i then KE_f - KE_i = -(U_f - U_i). I.e., KE_f + U_f = U_i _ KE_i...

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is due to the fact that you have not defined the system under consideration.

If you choose the two masses as the system then the gravitational force is an external force which does work on the system equal to $mgh$ and this work increases the kinetic energy of the system.

If you choose the two masses and the Earth as the system then you have a decrease in the gravitational potential energy of the system equal to $mgh$ and this work increases the kinetic energy of the masses.
Note here that one should really include the kinetic energy gained by the Earth but because the mass of the Earth is so much greater than that of the masses it is almost always not included.
If you are not sure about this point remember that when a mass falls down due the gravitational attraction of the Earth on the mass the Earth is also fall "up" due to the equal magnitude force on the Earth due to the gravitational attraction of the Earth.

A very important thing to remember about gravitational potential energy is that a system which comprises of just one mass cannot have any potential energy.
Again this point is usually ignored because the Earth is so large and so a statement that a mass has gravitational potential energy is used for convenience although it can lead to confusion like in this case.